# Python Django Mysql:ImportError: cannot import name Thing2Literal

Tags: python, mysql, django

When I am working with django, it came out that 'ImportError: cannot import name Thing2Literal'. I tried to make migrations from python to mysql but this problem came out. I have searched for many times, someone says it is the version of PyMysql that matters，but I have checked the version which may work well with my environment. My settings.py include the following code:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
]

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mysqlblogdb'),
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD' : 'sher',
        'HOST' : 'localhost',
        'PORT' : '3306',
    }
}
```

'blog' is my app,and the error came as:

```
sherdeMacBook-Pro:website sher$ python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in execute
django.setup()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setupapps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populateapp_config.import_models(all_models)
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 199, in import_models
self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
 File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 119, in __new__
new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 316, in add_to_class
value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__
backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 115, in load_backend
return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
 File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 31, in <module>
from MySQLdb.converters import Thing2Literal, conversions       # isort:skip
ImportError: cannot import name Thing2Literal
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mysqlblogdb'), ?? mysql wont look for a file, it will look for a database, that you need to create either from terminal or from gui and then pass the name only

Comment: Thank for your answer.os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '') is the default code that exists in setting.py for I use django 1.10. I just remove 'os.path.join',but it still came out same error.

Comment: do you have a database name called mysqlblogdb? and the settings would be something like this, DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME':'mysqlblogdb',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD' : 'sher',
        'HOST' : 'localhost',
        'PORT' : '3306',
    }
}

Comment: I have created a database named mysqlblogdb. Before I use MySQL, I use sqlite3, this works well with django. After that, I modified my code and tried to connect to MySQL,but it went wrong.

Comment: you need to create the database mysqlblogdb from mysql terminal or gui , do that and change the settings.py of database to what i gave and it will work

Comment: and yeah dont forget to do pip install mysqlconnector from the terminal for django to connect to mysql

Comment: In python shell, I use 'import MySQLdb',it works well. So I think mysqlconnector is working well. Actually there is mysqlblogdb in my computer, I created in mysqlworkbench.

Comment: ok so try to use your django project and see

Comment: the same error ><

Comment: did you run pip install mysqlconnector? if not install it and then check again

Comment: I have PyMySQL 0.7.11 ,you mean this one?

Comment: no that wont help, just run this  pip install mysqlconnector and then check the django project

Comment: It shows 'No matching distribution found for mysqlconnector' in shell.

Comment: sorry bro pip install mysqlclient

Comment: I got 'mysql-connector-python-cext==2.1.6',right?

Comment: what if you do mysqlclient? pip install mysqlclient and then run django project

Comment: successfully done but still same error

Comment: what is your django version bro?

Comment: 1.10.6   you Chinese?

Comment: no bro , do one thing, uninstall all the other mysqlconnectors and all you have and just keep the mysqlclient as the error is reported only for old versions of mysql-python

Comment: just keep mysqlclient in my computer?

Comment: yup for the mysql thing, other packages of mysql what you have uninstall them, bro not django and other libraries :P

Comment: you means this error is caused by the version of mysql connector. I should keep only one ?

Comment: yes bro, thats correct

Comment: !!!!!!!!It works!!!!!!!!!!!!  Thank you !!!!!!!!!! This problem has confused me several days. Enjoy django! Enjoy stackoverflow!

Comment: haha great bro :)

Comment: Still a question. Just as I tried before, I used PyMysql and other connectors,both these are latest. Why it didn't work? Just the mysqlclient that works?

Comment: those are now outdated,

Comment: I will study the specified difference between these connectors, thank you again!